# Use wlan0 or eth0 in different scripts / terminal

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, debian

I have a debian installation using eth0 and wlan0.
For all applications I want to use eth0 except for one single script I want to use wlan0.

Is there any possibility to force for example in a terminal session or in e.g. a shell script the usage of wlan0 for this specific script?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Please make sure you understand how to ask a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is quite easy to use `eth0` by default and then if you need to use `wlan0` for one run simply pass `wlan0` as a command-line argument. You should also check that the value you are using is either `eth0` or `wlan0`, or you should consider the argument invalid.

A short script that implements that logic would be:

```
#!/bin/sh

iface=${1:-eth0}  ## use eth0 by default or use the first argument

## if the iface entered is not eth0 or wlan0, handle error
if [ "$iface" != "eth0" ] && [ "$iface" != "wlan0" ]
then
    printf "error: invalid interface '%s'\n" "$iface"
    exit 1
fi

printf "using: %s\n" "$iface"  ## output interface being used
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh useiface.sh
using: eth0

$ sh useiface.sh wlan0
using: wlan0

$ sh useiface.sh eth1
error: invalid interface 'eth1'
```

You can see above when the user attempts to call the script with `eth1` that is not considered valid and the script provides an error and exits. You can adjust to fit your needs.

Comment: This question is very low quality. While I see the good faith, answering here is probably not the best choice.

Comment: Hello David, thanks a lot for your reply. I understand your script. It is just checking the input variables and defaulting eth0. But I do not see how you SET the current terminal session to use wlan0. I'm searching for the linux command to set for one script the interface to be used to wlan0 instead of going through the network of eth0. Hope this clarifies a bit. Thanks !

Comment: It is in the *parameter expansion* `iface=${1:-eth0}` where the expansion (in real terms says) `iface=$1` (the first positional parameter ... BUT if no argument (no `$1`) is given, then use `eth0` by default) So when `wlan0` is passed in as `$1`, then `iface=wlan0` (or it is set to anything else passed in as `$1`) which is why the `if` statement follows to make sure it is either `eth0` or `wlan0` and nothing else.

Comment: @hek2mgl - agreed, we can nuke it later after the learning is done.

Comment: @David C. Rankin I created a .sh scirpt including your code. After the if statement I call my script. Now this script is still using the eth0 ( in my case called enp0s25) and not the wlan0 (wlp2s0). I adjusted the script accordingly. I also tried to just set iface=wlp2s0 within the terminal and then call my script. Same issue it is using enp0s25. Do you have any other Idea how to debug this or any other solution on this? Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: @hek2mgl Sorry for the "poor" quality of question.